# Is there a monitoring and profiling tool for .Net solutions like VisualVM for Java?

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling

I want to view the heap and the objects inside them.  Is there a .net monitoring and profiling tool which I could use to view heaps and memory of a asp.net and C# application?

Comment: Also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at ANTS Memory Profiler and ANTS Performance Profiler from Red Gate:

ANTS Memory Profiler:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

ANTS Performance Profiler:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

For such affordable tools, they do a fantastic job of identifying bottlenecks and memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing the heap, you can use [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309515.aspx) or the [SOS Debugging Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404370.aspx) for the Visual Studio Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/), an open-source .Net profiler.